# Exclude a field from LinqToSql generated class item list

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, lambda

Is it possible to exclude a field from a collection of linq to sql generated class items.
A database table contains field of Image data type. The table has a lot of data inserted, so the programm dies when I try to receive all the items inserted. I need to have all the information except this field.

Sample code looks like:

```
arc_developDataContext _dataContext = new arc_developDataContext(connectionString);
_dataContext.arcs.OrderByDescending(a => a.arc_id)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this not what the 'Delay Loaded' property is for? See [here for more information](http://www.davidhayden.com/blog/dave/archive/2009/02/12/LINQToSQLTutorialsLazyLoadingPropertiesPerformance.aspx)